# Flutter suddenly stopped working with no known errors in the project code

Tags: android, flutter

I was working on my flutter app and when I called "flutter run" I suddenly got these error messages. Everything has been working fine for hours and this has never happened before. As far as I know, I didn't do anything that would've caused a problem.

```
Invalid depfile: C:\flutterapps\example\.dart_tool\flutter_build\b867e71f3290a539688bb57d29904221\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\flutterapps\example\.dart_tool\flutter_build\b867e71f3290a539688bb57d29904221\kernel_snapshot.d
lib/screens/development.dart:2:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:html';
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:html' is imported through these packages:

    package:flutter_blue_plus_example => dart:html

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

    package:flutter_blue_plus_example/main.dart => package:flutter_blue_plus_example/loading_screen.dart => package:flutter_blue_plus_example/screens/development.dart => dart:html

Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:733)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:871)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:678)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:102)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13)
<asynchronous suspension>

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\flutter_windows_3.13.9-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1357

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter_windows_3.13.9-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             54.3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: check for and remove the import of `dart:html` from your code

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue arising from importing 'dart:html' in the 'development.dart'. It would be a good idea to remove 'dart:html' first, and if any package import issues arise in the following code, using Alt+Enter to automatically import the necessary packages would be helpful.